# How are Old English participles declined to English participles? (both present and past)

Tags: etymology, old-english, germanic-languages

I'm trying to learn about differences between English and Old English, and I found that there are some noticeable differences in the use of participle markings. I think that participles were declined historically, but I want to get to know more details about the changes. (Are there any rules related to the changes?)

For example, Ic hæbbe ge-fręm-ed (I have performed.) -use of past participles. And Ic drīf-ende (I has driven) -use of present participle

Also, if anyone knows of good books for Old English grammar with great examples, please recommend them to me!
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "inclined"? Are you talking about the inflectional prefixes and suffixes that were used, or about the evolution in how participles are used?

Comment: Also can you give specific examples of what you are referring to? Short sentences or phrases or words?

Comment: yes. Inflectional prefixes and suffixed!

Comment: Sorry, I meant declensions of the inflectional participles.

Comment: For example, Ic hæbbe ge-fręm-ed (I have performed.) -use of past participles. And Ic drīf-ende (I has driven) -use of present participle

Comment: Declensions are generally different forms used in different grammatical cases. Past and present participles are part of the conjugation system of verbs.